# How to create an SSD disk using Google Compute Engine Java Client

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, solid-state-drive

I'm trying to create a disk using Java Compute Engine Client. What parameter do I have to set in order to make it SSD?
I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Found this... does it help? [Adding Local SSDs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd)

Comment: Nope... this is the CLI

Comment: You want a computer program to create a high tech physical item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to create a local SSD (attached to one instance, **not** durable but very fast), or a standard persistent disk backed by SSD?

For a standard persistent disk (which I'm guessing is what you want, as it can be backed up/snapshotted and survive when the VM is off), you'll want to [set the diskType to something like](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#create_disk) `/compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-east1-d/diskTypes/pd-ssd`:

> Alternatively, you can include the type property to create an SSD
>   persistent disk.
>
> ```
> POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-east1-d/disks
> {
>  "name": "example-disk-ssd",
>  "sizeGb": "100",
>  "type": "/compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-east1-d/diskTypes/pd-ssd"
> }
> ```

I'm not sure whether the Java client libraries provide an easy way to fill in the "my-project" and "us-east1-d" fields from your request, or if you have to repeat them yourself.

If you're looking for local SSD storage that only lives on the instance, the locally-attached storage [is a parameter to the
instance creation command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#creating_a_local_ssd) with type `SCRATCH` and diskType like `projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-f/diskTypes/local-ssd`:

> In the API, you can create a local SSD device when creating a virtual
>   machine instance by using the initializeParams property. You must also
>   provide the following properties:
>
> - diskType: Set to local SSD
> - autoDelete: Set to true
> - type: Set to SCRATCH

If you want a persistent disk backed by SSD,